# Comparing two collections of enums with Hibernate or SQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity 'Parent' which has a Set of enums

```
private Set<MyEnum> myEnums = EnumSet.noneOf(MyEnum.class);

    @CollectionOfElements(targetElement=MyEnum.class)
    @JoinTable
        (name="PARENT_MY_ENUM",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column (name="MY_ENUM", nullable=false)
    public Set<MyEnum> getMyEnums(){
        return myEnums;
    }


public MyEnum {
ENUM_A,
ENUM_B, 
ENUM_C,
ENUM_D;
}
```

Now I want to search for this entity with a collection of MyEnums. Only entities where all enums are set as in the search collection should be returned.
So if entity A has ENUM_A, ENUM_B and ENUM_C and entity B has ENUM_B, ENUM_C, ENUM_D a search with the search collectoin ENUM_A, ENUM_B, ENUM_C should only return entity A. A search for ENUM_B and ENUM_C should return nothing.

How would I do that in Hibernate?
if I do

```
select p from Parent p where p.myEnums IN (:searchCollection) and size(p.myEnums) = size(:searchCollection)
```

then this would return both entities for the first search.

Any ideas?

Update: I got a step further by figuring out how to do it in MySQL but applying this to Hibernate generates invalid SQL.
You would use a subquery with EXISTS for it like:

```
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT pa.PARENT_ID, count(pme.MY_ENUM) FROM PARENT pa, PARENT_MY_ENUM pme
    where pa.PARENT_ID = pme.PARENT_ID 
    AND pme.MY_ENUM IN ('ENUM_A','ENUM_B')
    GROUP BY pa.PARENT_ID HAVING count(pme.MY_ENUM) = 2
)
```

But when I try to do the same in Hibernate:

```
select pa.ParentId, count(pa.myEnums) from Parent pa 
WHERE pa.myEnums IN ('ENUM_A','ENUM_B')
GROUP BY pa.ParentId HAVING count(pa.myEnums) = 2
```

Hiberante creates this SQL statement:

```
select pa.CONTAINER_RELEASE_REFERENCE_ID as col_0_0_, count(.) as col_1_0_ from PARENT pa, PARENT_MY_ENUM enum1, PARENT_MY_ENUM enum2, PARENT_MY_ENUM enum3 
where pa.PARENT_ID=enum1.PARENT_ID and pa.PARENT_ID=enum2.PARENT_ID and pa.PARENT_ID=enum3.PARENT_ID 
and (. in ('ENUM_A' , 'ENUM_B')) 
group by pa.PARENT_ID having count(.)=2
```

MySQL complains about the '.', Where is that coming from and why is Hibernate using 3 joins to PARENT_MY_ENUM?

Is this a Hibernate bug or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the following a try for you exists subselect

```
select pa.ParentId, count(en) from Parent pa join pa.myEnums as en
WHERE en IN ('ENUM_A','ENUM_B')
GROUP BY pa.ParentId HAVING count(en) = 2
```

Otherwise, I wonder if something like that might not do the job

```
select p from Parent p join p.myEnums em
where (:results) = elements(em)
```

or

```
select p from Parent p join p.myEnums em
where (:results) in elements(em)
```

Comment: Thanks the extra join on the Enum did the trick. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that in java. Execute your initially proposed query, iterate the result and exclude (`iterator.remove()`) the false positives. It should be `O(n)`, and I believe MySQL will require the same time to filter your result.

Comment: It might be the same in terms of order of the problem however you also need to consider the amount of data transferred between the database and the application server (they might or might not be on the same server). Lets say only one percent of the result set will actually fit the criteria. So lets say in order to save on bandwidth (and time) between the appserver and the database you set the max results to 100, you only end up with one row. So while this might be a work around it doesn't really solve the problem.